# Trying to append multiple items to list but getting Python TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to loop through customfield_10003 and append all the "name" values in each customfield_10003 for each issue in the list.

Here is the JSON that im working on:

```
{
        "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
        "fields": {
            "customfield_10003": [
                {
                    "boardId": 11,
                    "completeDate": "2021-03-24T16:16:31.040Z",
                    "endDate": "2021-03-23T14:38:00.000Z",
                    "goal": "",
                    "id": 34,
                    "name": "Promo Sim 3/23",
                    "startDate": "2021-03-10T14:38:04.147Z",
                    "state": "closed"
                },
                {
                    "boardId": 11,
                    "completeDate": "2021-04-07T14:28:50.786Z",
                    "endDate": "2021-04-06T16:33:00.000Z",
                    "goal": "User will be able to create a new promotion simulator and include simulation inputs, select a simulation type. User will be able to view simulation inputs in the \"location\" they selected. User will be able to view predictors from a model on the Predictors tab. User will be able to view simulation inputs on the Spend tab.",
                    "id": 38,
                    "name": "Promo Sim 3",
                    "startDate": "2021-03-24T16:33:56.044Z",
                    "state": "closed"
                },
                {
                    "boardId": 11,
                    "completeDate": "2021-04-21T13:04:46.984Z",
                    "endDate": "2021-04-20T22:26:00.000Z",
                    "goal": "Ability to Publish a Predictive Model, Ability to calculate promo sim metrics, View Summary Results with calced metrics (using the predictor data inserted into backend**)",
                    "id": 39,
                    "name": "Promo Sim 4",
                    "startDate": "2021-04-07T12:12:30.195Z",
                    "state": "closed"
                }
            ],
            "summary": "Simulation Type - Fix \"Remove\" button display & Update \"Volume Components\" to \"Simulation Input\""
        },
        "id": "25391",
        "key": "PA-4699",
        "self": "N/A"
    }
```

Here is the Python code that i have written which currently ONLY gets the "name" value of the [0] customfield_10003 in the list. Im not sure how to loop through the list and append each "name" value to the issue list output.

```
issue_list = []
for issue in issues:
  if issue['fields']["customfield_10003"]:
    issue_list.append([issue['key'],issue['fields']['summary'],issue["fields"] 
    ["customfield_10003"][0]["name"]])
else:
  issue_list.append([issue['key'],issue['fields']['summary']])enter code here
```

Comment: please correct the json. it is not valid

Comment: Updated the json and verified that its valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can better describe your desired output, then a better answer can be provided.

This iterates through your json object and pulls the names into a list

```
#data = your sample json
data1 = data['fields']['customfield_10003']
names_list = [d['name'] for d in data1]

['Promo Sim 3/23', 'Promo Sim 3', 'Promo Sim 4']
```